# Laravel Mix 6 ver upgrade error in webpack.mix.js

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

My task is to upgrade package.json in Laravel.
I haven't had any problems using Laravel-Mix 5 ver until now, but when I run "yarn run", got the following error after switching to 6 ver.

> [webpack-cli] Error: You must compile JS to extract vendor code
> at Extract.webpackEntry (/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Extract.js:46:19)
> at /var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js:112:53
> at /var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:39:62
> at Array.map ()
> at Dispatcher.fire (/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:39:47)
> at Mix.dispatch (/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:248:32)
> at WebpackConfig.buildEntry (/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:62:24)
> at WebpackConfig.build (/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:27:20)
> at Mix.build (/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:89:35)
> at module.exports (/var/www/html/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:16:16)
> error Command failed with exit code 2. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command.

I support it's maybe due to webpack.mix.js.
The file is below.
※Partially modified.

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const SentryWebpackPlugin = require("@sentry/webpack-plugin");

require("laravel-mix-react-typescript-extension");
require("laravel-mix-merge-manifest");

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

const additionalEnvPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": {
    APP_TYPE: JSON.stringify("admin"),
    SENTRY_DSN: JSON.stringify(process.env.SENTRY_DSN),
    DEVICE: JSON.stringify("pc"),
  },
});

const isSentryActive =
  process.env.SENTRY_DSN !== undefined && process.env.SENTRY_DSN !== "";

const sentryWebpackPlugin = new SentryWebpackPlugin({
  dryRun: !isSentryActive,
  setCommits: {
    repo: "sample/sample-server",
    commit: process.env.SENTRY_RELEASE,
  },
  deploy: {
    env: process.env.MIX_ENV
  },
  include: "./public/pc/admin",
  urlPrefix: `${process.env.SENTRY_APP_URL}/pc/admin/`,
  release: process.env.SENTRY_RELEASE,
});

mix
  .reactTypeScript(
    "resources/react/pc/admin/chat/index.tsx",
    "public/pc/admin/components/chat"
  )
  .extract(["react"], "public/pc/admin/components/chat/vendor.js")
  .mergeManifest()
  .sourceMaps(mix.inProduction(), "source-map")
  .webpackConfig({
    plugins: [additionalEnvPlugin, sentryWebpackPlugin],
  });

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version();
}
```

My env

- PHP: 7.4.29
- Laravel :8.76.2
- Yarn: 1.22.5
- Node: 16.14.2
- Laravel Mix: 6.0.43